# Aligning error bars for grouped bar chart using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a grouped bar chart where the x axis is date. My error bars won't exactly align in the center, even though my position dodge is equal to the width of the bars.

Here is my code:

```
SZ<- data.frame(Date=rep(c("2021-6-9", "2021-7-7", "2021-8-3", "2021-9-2", "2021-9-30"),3),
                Site=rep(c("SZA", "SZB", "SZC"),each=5),
                Flux=c(2.353333333, 3.33,   4.46,   3.97,   3.2,    1.92,   2.693333333,    4.27,   1.91,   2.536666667,    5.8,    5.776666667,    5.663333333,    3.946666667,    3.216666667
                ),
                sd=c(0.903, 1.453, 0.744, 1.0897, 1.0661, 0.243, 0.481, 0.275, 1.248, 0.501, 1.067, 0.531, 0.818, 0.338, 0.628)
)
head(SZ)

SZ$date <- factor(SZ$Date, levels = unique(SZ$Date))

SZ$date <- as.Date(SZ$date)

p <- ggplot(data=SZ, aes(x=date, y=Flux, fill=Site)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width= 4, position=position_dodge())+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Flux-sd, ymax=Flux+sd, group=Site), 
                position=position_dodge(4), width = 1, size = 0.3)
p
```

And here is the output image.

[image]

You can probably see best on the second blue bar that it is not centered, but for some of the bars they are centered.  I'm wondering if this is an issue with the date formatting of the x axis because there is an unequal number of days in between each sample date. I have also toggled the width and size and that hasn't changed anything. The caps also aren't even, sometimes they only show on one side of the error bar. Any help very much appreciated

Comment: Looks like some of your code got cut off.

Comment: I cannot replicate this behavior, your code results in perfectly centered error bars for me. Maybe you should update your ggplot2 package to a newer version? Or maybe the resolution of the PNG is too low – try rendering a PDF?

Comment: I think this is an issue with resolution. Within RMarkdown I also see off center error bars, but it renders correctly as a png from `ggsave` with sufficient resolution. Smaller image sizes I also see off-center bars.

Comment: Hi @TrainingPizza,  ggsave resolved the issue for me, thank you! I am newer to R, I originally used export in the plot window instead of ggsave. Could you tell me why ggsave works and export does not?

Comment: @a_wil The main difference is the resolution. The default dpi for `ggsave` is 300, while I believe export from the RStudio viewer is 72. Using `dpi = 72` in `ggsave` with the same dimensions as export will yield similar results. There is more nuance than that, but I would say that's the primary reason.

Comment: Small correction: default dpi for export is 96 (in Windows at least) so using `dpi = 96` and the same dimensions in `ggsave` should have identical results.